# VS Code: Options parameter in tasks.json not able to change env variables?

Tags: visual-studio-code, environment-variables, vscode-tasks

I have the following tasks.json file with the options declared in the windows section

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Bazel Build (Debug)",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "bazel  build --cxxopt='-std=c++17' ${relativeFileDirname}:${fileBasenameNoExtension} -c dbg",
      
      "windows": {
        "options": {
          "env": {
            "relativeFileDirname": "src/main" 
          }
        },
        "command": "bazel build --cxxopt='-std=c++17' ${relativeFileDirname}:${fileBasenameNoExtension} --enable_runfiles -c dbg --verbose_failures"
      }
    }
   ]
 }
```

I am trying to change the relativeFileDirname environment paramter to src/main from src\main as Bazel is still looking for unix like directory separators, even on windows.

How can I get the options to change the environment variable for the windows build task only?

Comment: Why? Windows recognizes the Unix convention of using a forward slash to separate path components. I don't use VSCode but it seems odd that a "windows" section would override the "command" definition in the outer context. And where is "relativeFileDirname" defined? Is it really an "env" var that can be changed in the manner you are attempting?

Comment: The issue is, I have VSCode in the Windows envirnment and am trying to debug a bazel c++ project that seems to want the forward slash (/) instead of the back slash (\) looking for a way to search and replace in the config before the command with path gets executed.

Comment: Got a workaround - rather than using windows and try to build bazel, I gave up and switched to Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) on my windows machine, installed VS Code in WSL and Bazel now builds as it is UNIX native.